# For SSH access only, do I leave `#PubkeyAuthentication yes` commented out in sshd_config, or uncomment it?

Tags: ssh, debian, public-key

Just setting up a new Debian 10 server having uploaded my public SSH keys, not restarted sshd yet.

I can now log in without password, so now doing all the usual recommended edits in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

- `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no`
- `usePAM no`
- `PermitRootLogin no`
- `PasswordAuthentication no`

**BUT** I'm wondering if leaving `#PubkeyAuthentication yes` commented out means "no setting" i.e. as some posts seem to indicate I can still SSH in pw-free without explicitly uncommenting this line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man sshd_config` will show you that `yes` is the default value for `PubkeyAuthentication`. So you can leave it commented out; it's the same as `yes`.

The stock `sshd_config` file also includes a comment at the top, saying that it comes with the default values present but commented out.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought as much but wasn't absolutely sure.

Comment: Read more https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config about it before making changes.